# rails not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed rails a while back.
Now when I do `rails new foo`  at the terminal nothing happens.
I have ruby 1.9.2. When I do gem list, I can see rails (3.2.8). However executing any rails commands, including `rails` itself does nothing.

I also tried `sudo gem cleanup` and `sudo gem clean`. `sudo gem uninstall rails` and then  `sudo gem install rails`. This gives me

```
Fetching: rails-3.2.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-3.2.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.8...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.8...
file 'lib' not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The problem was that I had defined a shell alias called rails which was masking rails.

Comment: Did you also do `rails new foo` again after the install ?

Comment: Yes. Its the same thing. It does nothing. I can only run rails as sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Do `gem install rails` - no `sudo`

Then `rails new foo`

Comment: Rails works fine when I do sudo rails new foo but even after I run the above command, I cannot run rails without sudo

Comment: When I run the above command I get the error "You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.". I think if I can put the gems directory somewhere in my home directory, it should solve the problem

Comment: This is not necessarily true, depends on how Ruby was installed.